# SQL: value not same between app and database

Tags: sql, database, types

there is one transaction in the database have huge number 8,000,008 PCS but actually this number is only 8 PCS in the app. there is no way to enter this number by mistake in data entry level because there is condition to not enter number greater than 1000. so i am asking why this huge number appear in database?
i am asking for the reason to make this strange issue and if there is any solution?[Press Here to get database result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8R5Q4.jpg)
[Press Here to get app result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RNNq8.jpg)

Comment: maybe it was entered manually into the DB. 
Try to log all ´ inserts´  so you can reproduce the erroneous situation next time.

Comment: Look for and log the application `INSERT` related to that row or any inserted rows in the future, so you'll have some proof of the SQL executed.  You'll likely find you have an application mistake in generating that insert or the error is in your query to read data from the table.  It's probably not an SQL issue.  If you think it's SQL related, include the exact SQL executed that produces the result you don't understand.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.